# SharePoint SSOM memory leak

Tags: sharepoint, memory-leaks

I have noticed a memory leak in my SharePoint console app.
App creates site collections and subwebs like this

```
 using(SPSite site = new SPSite(rootUrl))
 {
            using(SPSite newSite = site.WebApplication.Sites.Add(...))
            {
                 foreach(var s in subwebs) // subwebs is just a collection of models with title, url etc
                 {
                     Logger.Log(...);                         
                     using (SPWeb web = newSite.AllWebs.Add(s.Url)) 
                     {
                        Logger.Log(...);
                     } // SPWeb disposed
                 } // SPSite disposed
            } // SPSite disposed
        }
```

Memory consumption increases significantly when this app runs for a few hours.
Yes, it creates thousands of subwebs for dozens of site collections.
Memory consumption is over 1.5 GiB after 4-5 hours. 
SPSite and SPWebs are properly disposed (or they seem like it) and most of memory is consumed by **Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager** (according to memory profiler data).

What can cause that?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly disposing all the SPSite and SPWeb objects before the end of their `using` blocks via the `.Dispose()` member method? If that doesn't resolve the problem, we might need to see the details of your `Logger.Log()` method.

Comment: Here is Logger.Log signature `void Log(params string[] messages);`
Im only logging that `SPSite` or `SPWeb` was created and passing its url: `Logger.Log('SPWeb created:', web.Url);`
Gonna try explicit `Dispose` now, thanks.

Comment: It seems like `SPSite` object has internal dictionary which stores all SPWeb objects being created via `new SPWeb()` or `SPWebCollection.Add` method until `SPSite` itself is disposed.